# i am gettting org.json.JSONException: No value for an item , which is present in my json array

Tags: java, android, json

even though i have "feels_like" in my json array which you could see in log info in errors it is showing it is not present

CODE:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            String weather = jsonObject.getString("weather");
            String temperature = jsonObject.getString("main");
            String ans = weather + temperature;
            Log.i("ans",ans);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(ans);
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonpart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                getweather.setText(jsonpart.getString("feels_like") + "\n" + jsonpart.getString("description"));

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

ERROR:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default 2020-04-16 08:07:54.896
14696-14696/com.example.myweather I/ans:[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}]{"temp":4.62,"feels_like":1.84,"temp_min":1.67,"temp_max":7.78,"pressure":1017,"humidity":81}
2020-04-16 08:07:54.898 14696-14696/com.example.myweather W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for feels_like
2020-04-16 08:07:54.899 14696-14696/com.example.myweather W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
```

Comment: according to the stack trace the value "feels_like" isn't in the JSONArray, it placed in the JSONObject, so try to get it like this: jsonObject.getDouble("feels_like")

Comment: {"coord":{"lon":72.85,"lat":19.01},"weather":[{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":32.51,"feels_like":35.08,"temp_min":32,"temp_max":33,"pressure":1011,"humidity":63},"visibility":4000,"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":230},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1587018350,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9052,"country":"IN","sunrise":1586998219,"sunset":1587043557},"timezone":19800,"id":1275339,"name":"Mumbai","cod":200}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);          // get root json object
JSONObject main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main"); // get "main" json object from root
Double feelsLike = main.getDouble("feels_like");    // get "feels_like" value from main
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace, It looks there is no key(feels_like) in the JSON or tries to access from the wrong JSONObject.  If you post the JSON Structure might help to understand better.